# How do I get rid of errors in an array in Excel? ISERROR and IFERROR are not working

Tags: arrays, excel

I have this formula:

```
{=IF(R2=TRUE,Machines!B22:L39,IF(R1=TRUE,Table3[#All],IF(R3=TRUE,Machines!B2:L21,IF(R4=TRUE,Machines!B55:L59,IF(R5=TRUE,Machines!B45:L50,"")))))}
```

which brings up a table when a check box is true.  The tables are different sizes so they don't all use up the same space in the array, which signals errors.

I have tried `ISERROR` and `IFERROR` with no success. `ISERROR` just returns the same table with the same errors and `IFERROR` returns more errors about too many arguments, and then highlights the table in Machines!.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in INDEX and call one cell at a time. Put this in the first cell:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(IF($R$2=TRUE,Machines!$B$22:$L439,IF($R$1=TRUE,Table3[#All],IF($R$3=TRUE,Machines!$B$2:$L$21,IF($R$4=TRUE,Machines!$B$55:$L$59,IF($R$5=TRUE,Machines!$B$45:$L$50,""))))),ROW(1:1),COLUMN(A:A)),"")
```

Enter as a normal formula then copy over and down the size of your largest range dimensions.

Again not an array formula.  It will change the `ROW(1:1)` and `COLUMN(A:A)` will change as it is copied/dragged and refer to a different part of the range array.  If the row and column are beyond the extents of the range it will return an error that `IFERROR` can catch.